How could i display a pdf file as an image in C# winform?
I'm new in C# and I have create a scanner application by C# winform. Now I'm having a problem that when i use treeview for a folder and click in item inside (all items inside are images and pdf file). All image file format display normal in picture box but when i try to display for pdf file it not working, my app just notice that is not a pdf file but the file i click in totally in a pdf file. Does anyone have some advise
private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Node != null && e.Node.Tag != null && File.Exists(e.Node.Tag.ToString()))
    {
        string selectedFile = e.Node.Tag.ToString();
        if (File.Exists(selectedFile))
        {
            if (IsImageFile(selectedFile))
            {
                try
                {
                    if (IsPdfFile(selectedFile))
                    {
                        if (selectedFile.ToLower().EndsWith(".pdf"))
                        {
                            using (PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument document = PdfiumViewer.PdfDocument.Load(selectedFile))
                            {
                                int imageIndex = treeView1.SelectedNode.Index;
                                using (Bitmap image = (Bitmap)document.Render(imageIndex, 300, 300, true))
                                {
                                    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(image);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(selectedFile);
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error loading file: " + ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Selected file is not an image or PDF.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Selected file does not exist.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }
}

private bool IsImageFile(string fileName)
{
    string[] validExtensions = { ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".png", ".gif", ".bmp" };
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    return validExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower());
}

private bool IsPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    string[] pdfExtensions = { ".pdf" };
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
    return pdfExtensions.Contains(extension.ToLower());
}

private void PopulateTreeView(string directory, TreeNode parentNode)
{
    if (parentNode == null)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Clear();
    }

    DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    TreeNode node = new TreeNode(directoryInfo.Name);
    node.Tag = directoryInfo.FullName;

    node.ImageIndex = 0;
    node.SelectedImageIndex = 0;

    if (parentNode == null)
    {
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(node);
    }
    else
    {
        parentNode.Nodes.Add(node);
    }

    try
    {
        foreach (var dir in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            PopulateTreeView(dir.FullName, node);
        }

        foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
        {
            TreeNode fileNode;
            if (IsImageFile(file.FullName))
            {
                fileNode = new TreeNode(file.Name);

                fileNode.ImageIndex = 1;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = 1;
            }
            else if (IsPdfFile(file.FullName))
            {
                fileNode = new TreeNode(file.Name);
                fileNode.ImageIndex = 2;
                fileNode.SelectedImageIndex = 2;
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
            fileNode.Tag = file.FullName;
            node.Nodes.Add(fileNode);
        }
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
    {
        node.Nodes.Add("Access denied");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        node.Nodes.Add("Error: " + ex.Message);
    }
}


do you need to show the pdf as picture (only the very first page) or show the pdf as an embedded document inside your form. For the former you need a library that will convert the pdf first page to picture (to show later in that same picturebox you are using for regular images), for the latter you need a document viewer to embed in your form.  For this latter scenario, I think the easiest approach would be using a ``WebBrowserWinForm control and then use theNavigatemethod as for example:webBrowser1.Navigate(filePath);`

Reading between the lines. Pdfium, that you seem to use, tells you the file you gave to it isn't a valid PDF file? Have you checked that it is valid by other means? If it seems valid what is exact error you get?

@DiegoD just only the very first page sir

@Ralf I have checked in a browser that it is a pdf file.  The weird thing is that I don't know what error I get.

@LongPham I didn't notice that you actually already attempted the route of converting the pdf to image using pdfium as the other user pointed out. I think you should strip down your code to isolate this very narrow scenario. You should focus on a pdf file you know exists at a given path and its a valid pdf and just understand what's going on when you try to convert it to picture with that library. If it doesn't work you need to find out the errors and solve them.. but starting from a pdf you know that works for sure

Maybe it doesn't fail but you have a problem with image size vs pdf size? If you want to render a 100 pages pdf into 300px height the pages in the image gets pretty narrow (maybe even less then a pixel) so you wouldn't see anything. That's under the assumption that here all pages are rendered and aspect ratio is maintained by your Pdfium library.

@DiegoD I have tried to use OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog() and my pdf file (only the very first page) displays well.

Looking at your code again you are checking IsPdfFile inside a IsImageFile block. Both checks/methods are mutual exclusive. A PDF file is not both. I would advice you to simply debug your code and see if you actually reach the PDF code.

@Ralf thank you, I have separated both checks/methods and it works.
